# an unhanded Microsoft.net framework exception occurred in devenv.exe[1692]

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, project

When I try to open visual studio 2015 and create a project, there appears a window, which says

```
Visual Studio 2015 has stopped working
```

When I press debug, I get the following error message

```
an unhandled microsoft.net framework exception occurred in devenv.exe[1692]
```

How can I fix this, please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that VS IDE was crashed.

**An unhandled microsoft.net framwork exception occurred in devenv.exe[1692]**

Go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > double click - Microsoft .net framework client profile, please repair it and then restart your machine, view the result.

If all projects still have this issue, I suggest you repair your VS, please also install the update 3.

If still no help, one idea is that collect the crash dump file, and then debug the dump file in your side.

Update:

If it works well in safe mode with: Devenv.exe/safemode, I suggest you view your VS IDE, did you install any VS extension tools in your side after you install the VS, generally it would be related to the add-ins or extension tools in your VS if it works well in safe mode.

Of course, to make sure that it was not the .net framework setup issue, you could use this tool:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/

Comment: @seyed_vahid, Did you get any error message during you install the VS? If you run your VS as the admin or run it in safe mode(Devenv.exe/safemode), how about the result?

Comment: I unistall it and install again but do not solve.i  can not find Microsoft .net framework client profil in specified path ,what do i do?When i repair it do not solve.when run it as the safe mode work good but when run it as the admin do not work.

Comment: @seyed_vahid, I just edit my answer, if possible, you could refer to it. If it works well in safe mode, maybe it was not the .NET Framework setup issue, we would think about the VS extension or add-ins in your Environment.

Comment: @seyed_vahid, If you get any update, please share it, I will follow up it in time.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue, but with Visual Studio 2013. After trying a lot to resolve this issue, I finally decided to uninstall VS 2013 completely and reinstall it again. Surprisingly this fixed the problem.

Also, I recommend using the .NET verification tool to see that there is no issue with the installed .NET frameworks. More details on this here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/